# How is Basic4Android IDE to create complex application

Tags: android, basic4android

I am planning to create a complex application which has lots of Database requests and Network data sending back and forth. Is it advisable to use Basic4Android(B4A). I am confused ? I downloaded the trail version and liked it because its easy atleast at the beginning, don't know about later examples. The points am concerned about is

```
1> Is it possible to Customize Controls Easily using Basic4Android. 
2> Is it fast as compared to Eclipse in terms of understanding and coding time. 
3> Updating Application later when want to add new features. 
4> Can the API available for android can be used in Basic4Android, Like the jar files which we add as external jars to the classpath can that be done in B4A? 
5> Also can a plugin kind of application be made in Android , if yes then is it possible using B4A?
```

If someone has made application using B4A please Guide me.
Currently am trying the examples from the guide the B4A guys have on the web and am finding it amazing. But I need an expert "REVIEW" who has previously worked on B4A.
 I need to work on application ASAP.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1> Is it possible to Customize Controls Easily using Basic4Android.

Yes, you can use images,panel and reflection lib to customize

2> Is it fast as compared to Eclipse in terms of understanding and coding time.

Yes learning curve is very short

3> Updating Application later when want to add new features.

You can save the b4a project and change when ever you need to update.

4> Can the API available for android can be used in Basic4Android, Like the jar files which we add as external jars to the classpath can that be done in B4A?

You can add (wrap) external jar files in Eclipse or use B4A Simple Library Compiler. Check out tutorials. You can also make your own libraries

5> Also can a plugin kind of application be made in Android , if yes then is it possible using B4A?

Depends on what plugin you want to make. The source code of apk created by B4A app is stored in src folder. You need to check out whether it can be incorporated in your android IDE.